# What is best way to learn Spring AOP or AOP in general?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have got experience working in Spring framework, but i find it very difficult to  understand the basics of Spring AOP or AOP in general. Could you guys suggest me some good online tutorials/books you have come across to learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned by reading [AspectJ Documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php).

- [Getting Started](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting.html)
- [AspectJ Programming Guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html)

I've found that these docs prepared me well enough to dive into Spring AOP without too much of a fuss.

Answer (score 3):

[Ramnivas Laddad's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930110936) is very good indeed.

Comment: There is now a second edition of that book (September 2010):
http://www.manning.com/laddad2/

A lot has happened in seven years.

Answer (score 2):

There are some videos which can help you to Learn AOP fast.
(In total just 1 hour)

go to ->[spring tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdyLsX0nG30&list=PLE37064DE302862F8)(videos 24,25,26 and 27)

they give you a fast start.After watching videos it will be much easier for you to go in details which you can from  ->[spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html)

Comment: these tutorials are good place to start spring.on your own

Comment: these links are no longer valid. Any alternate links available?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial that just appeared on DZone:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-spring-aop

Also, I definitely won't claim that this is the *best* way to learn Spring AOP, but I wrote a short article showing how to use Spring AOP (with AspectJ annotations) to cause method calls to execute on a separate thread:

http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-javamail-aop.html

Also as duffymo said, Ramnivas Laddad's book is a good starting point.